# Filtering ComboBox.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filter, combobox

I'm trying to make a `ComboBox` filter its `ItemsSource` based on a `FilterValue` string bound to its `Text`; the control is inside the `CellEditingTemplate` of a `DataGrid`, which is itself inside a `DataTemplate`. The items all implement an `ICodeName` interface that guarantees there's a `Code` and a `Name` property, and I'm successfully using an `ItemTemplate` that leverages those.

So the context of a `DataGridRow` is a `Foo`, a view-model class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and exposes a `Bars` property, which is an `ICollectionView` ("SuggestionBox" is a user control inheriting `ComboBox`):

```xaml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bar">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SuggestionBox Text="{Binding FilterValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Bars, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CodeNameDropdownTemplate}">
            </local:SuggestionBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The grid-row item class (`Foo`) exposes these:

```
private ICollectionView _bars;
public ICollectionView Bars
{
    get { return _bars; }
    set
    {
        if (_bars != value)
        {
            _bars = value;
            _bars.Filter = FilterBars;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private bool FilterBars(object obj)
{
    var item = (ICodeName)obj;
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterValue) 
        || item.Code.Contains(FilterValue) 
        || item.Name.Contains(FilterValue);
}

private string _filterValue;
public string FilterValue
{
    get
    {
        return _filterValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_filterValue != value)
        {
            _filterValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Bars.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I can see the `Bars` listed in the dropdown; when I type in the "suggestion box", a breakpoint set in the `FilterValue` setter is hit - however `FilterBars` is never invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the concrete type of the `ICollectionView`?

Comment: @redcurry it's a `CollectionView`, wrapping an `ObservableCollection<ICodeName>` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried something similar, using a `CollectionView` actually generated a warning for me:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 53 : Using CollectionView directly is not fully supported.  The basic features work, although with some inefficiencies, but advanced features may encounter known bugs.  Consider using a derived class to avoid these problems.
```

Instead of instantiating a `CollectionView` directly, you can do the following:

```
Bars = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(codeNames);
```

That will instantiate a `ListCollectionView`, which derives from `CollectionView`. By the way, `codeNames` is just the variable I gave to your `ObservableCollection<ICodeName>`.

Finally, even though you're refreshing the `ICollectionView` in the `FilterValue` setter, you still need to tell WPF to refresh its view. In other words, you need to raise `PropertyChanged` on `Bars`.